# HTML Form Submission E-mail Formatting

Tags: html, forms, email

First time question-asker here.

I have adopted some code for a form that, upon submission, sends an e-mail to the user containing a confirmation of all the data s/he submitted.

In the code that creates the e-mail, I am seeing these symbols a lot:

```
<?
?>
<?=
```

I have had a lot of trouble trying to google what these symbols refer to (when I type it into google, it doesn't acknowledge that any text has been input!), but it seems clear that they are pulling the values from the form based on element names. I have been able to mimic the syntax the creator used in most cases, but I have run into an issue.

If I do:

```
<?= form.peerEvalCount ?>
```

It pulls the value from the field named "peerEvalCount" and incorporates it into the e-mail as text, which is perfect.

**How can I have the same functionality without having to specify the name of the field in that line?**

For instance, I would like to do something like:

```
var variable = "peerEvalCount"
<?= form.variable ?>
```

The reason is that I would like to incorporate this into a loop where I have a series of element names that are iterative (tax1, tax2, tax3, etc.). The number of such elements varies depending on who is using the form, so I can't simply hard-code them in...

Comment: <? and ?> tags indicate PHP code, not HTML. It would also be useful if you provided the link to the source your code is adapted from.

Comment: `form.peerEvalCount` suggests it isn't PHP though.

Comment: Patrick L - how do i identify this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is javascript and possibly PHP.

I would start with googling how to send an e-mail form using PHP, and then use javascript for your form validation.

This link should help you out:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html